# RegEx with Powershell wrong?

Tags: windows, powershell

So I have this PowerShell one-liner that gives me back my groups:

```
$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership userName | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Name -BackgroundColor Red} |Out-String; $groupsWithSpaces = foreach ($groups in $groupsWithSpaces) {Select-String -AllMatches '[\\s+,]' | Write-Host}; Write-Host $groupsWithSpaces
```

How am I using the regex wrong? I am trying to return only groups that have a whitespace on the end. I am always returning every group, and I only want the ones that have white space on the end. I can get true/false, but...help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex you were escaping one of the slashes. Making it so you were looking for groups with a literal slash followed by at least on letter s.

If you are just trying to find the group with spaces in them this would work

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match "\s"} | 
    select -ExpandProperty Name | 
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor red
```

I formatted it for easy reading

If you wanted to see the whole list with the empty ones standing out you could also use and if statement

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object{
    If( $_ -match  "\s"){
        Write-Host $_ -BackgroundColor red
    } Else {
        Write-Host $_
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the false variable --> `$groupsWithSpaces = foreach ($groups in -->HERE<--$groupsWithSpaces-->HERE<--) {Select-String -AllMatches '[\\s+,]' | Write-Host}; Write-Host $groupsWithSpaces`.
Work this one?

```
$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership userName | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Name -BackgroundColor Red} |Out-String; $groupsWithSpaces = foreach ($group in $groups) {If ($group[-1] -eq " ") {Write-Host $group}}; Write-Host $groupsWithSpaces
```

Comment: I can't paste the output, but it's returning the same as my variant. Although thanks for grabbing the false variable.